# Translation of 'lying over' to portuguese

Tags: algebraic-geometry, translation-request

I would like to know if the mathematical term "lying over property" (on context of algebraic geometry) has a specific translate to portuguese. The translate would be  "propriedade de deitar", but this seems not good. Thank you for attention!

Comment: As a disclaimer, I know zero Portuguese, but I used Google translate on what you wrote and it definitely looks wrong. Like I said I know none, but I would guess "propriedade de cobertura" would be closer.

Comment: Or "propriedade de cobrir de cima"

Comment: Propriedade de cobertura seems a good name in Portuguese, maybe you are correct! Thank you for attention.

Comment: Sure, no problem.